# How to export a MLFlow Model from Azure Databricks as an Azure DevOps Artifacts for CD phase?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks, mlflow

I am trying to create an MLOps Pipeline using Azure DevOps and Azure Databricks. From Azure DevOps, I am submitting a Databricks job to a cluster, which trains a Machine Learning Model and saves it into MLFlow Model Registry with a custom flavour (using PyFunc Custom Model).

Now after the job gets over, I want to export this MLFlow Object (with all dependencies - Conda dependencies, two model files - one `.pkl` and one `.h5`, the Python Class with `load_context()` and `predict()` functions defined so that after exporting I can import it and call predict as we do with MLFlow Models).

How do I export this entire MLFlow Model and save it as an AzureDevOps Artifact to be used in the CD phase (where I will deploy it to an AKS cluster with a custom base image)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official way to export a Databricks MLflow run from one workspace to another. However, there is an "unofficial" tool that does most of the job with the main limitation being that notebook revisions linked to a run cannot be exported due to lack of a REST API endpoint for this.

https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-export-import

Answer (score 0):

Probably you needn't to use the artifacts, there is an azure devops extension ([Machine Learning](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-air-aiagility.vss-services-azureml)), it can access artifacts in the AzureML workspace, and trigger the release pipeline. You can refer to link below for the steps：
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MLOpsDatabricks/blob/master/docs/release-pipeline.md

Comment: We are not using AzureML. We intend to use Azure DevOps and Azure Databricks.